# Accessing Kubernetes master and nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

I created 1 AWS ec2 instance and using that I setup kubernetes cluster 1 master with  2 nodes(using kops) and it's running properly. now i want to access kubernetes cluster in another aws ec2 instance how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have created `Amazon S3 bucket` for each cluster. Now you have to export `KOPS_STATE_STORE` variable for each cluster for kops to know which environment to load.

Something like the following:

cluster_1.env:

> export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://aws-kops-bucket-1

cluster_2.env:

> export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://aws-kops-bucket-2

If you are running these clusters under two different accounts, you also need to export `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` variables for the given s3 bucket's account authorization.into each .env file appropriate credentials:

> export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=id_key
>   export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key

So, in order to switch the cluster, you would just need `source cluster_1.env` or `source cluster_2.env` that would load the desired environment.

I also found a GitHub issue for kops [Enable Cluster Switching - Map kops clusters to aws buckets and profiles #1177](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1177) that might be helpful to you.